# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException WebDriver in Java?

Tags: java, webdriver

I have a problem with WebDriver Java class, when I want to get an attribute type "textArea"

I get this Exception.

Code:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("http://www.cmmazzoni.it/index.php?option=com_jdownloads&Itemid=0&view=upload");
WebElement descriptionOne=driver.findElement(By.name("description"));
descripcionUno.sendKeys("Hola! :D");
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: You may only set the value of elements that are input elements
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitKeyboard.sendKeys(HtmlUnitKeyboard.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.sendKeys(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:343)
    at Modelo.HiloPaginas.subibirImagencom_jdownloads(HiloPaginas.java:219)
    at Modelo.HiloPaginas.run(HiloPaginas.java:108)
```

Comment: Please ask your question in english.

Comment: the selector which you have used might be wrong please cross check.. and also according to the error description says that you are trying to enter text in an element which was not allowd check whether the Text area i Read-only  or not

Comment: Can you drop the htmlCode of the element which you are trying to automate...it could help to solve the issue

Comment: @DeviKiran the element where he is trying to enter is under an iframe...

Answer (score 0):

The reason it ain't working is cause the element where u need to enter text is in a iframe. Please try out following code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(
        driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).get(0));
WebElement descriptionOne = driver
    .findElement(By.className("editbox"));
descriptionOne.sendKeys("Hola! :D");
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you are calling wrong webElement name to sendkeys:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("http://www.cmmazzoni.it/index.php?option=com_jdownloads&Itemid=0&view=upload");
WebElement descriptionOne=driver.findElement(By.name("description"));
descripcionUno.sendKeys("Hola! :D");
```

Please use "descriptionOne.sendKeys("Hola! :D");" instead of "descripcionUno.sendKeys("Hola! :D");"

Let me know if it works for you. Cheers!