# How get textArea using Java with WebDriver?

Tags: java, webdriver

I have a problem with WebDriver Java class, when I want to get an attribute type "textArea" I get this Exception.

Code:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(); driver.get("http://www.cmmazzoni.it/index.php?option=com_jdownloads&Itemid=0&view=upload");                

WebElement descriptionOne=driver.findElement(By.name("description"));
descripcionUno.sendKeys("Hola! :D");
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: You may only set the value of elements that are input         elements
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitKeyboard.sendKeys(HtmlUnitKeyboard.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.sendKeys(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:343)
at Modelo.HiloPaginas.subibirImagencom_jdownloads(HiloPaginas.java:219)
at Modelo.HiloPaginas.run(HiloPaginas.java:108)
```

Code HTML:

```
<td width="140" valign="top">Descripción Corta:
</td><td width="20" valign="top">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">
<textarea cols="75" rows="20" style="width:100%; height:350px;" id="description"     name="description"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">window.addEvent("domready",function()
{CKEDITOR.config.expandedToolbar = true;
Replacedescription_longTextContainer("description"); 
});
</script><
</td>
```

Comment: pls check answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27684016/org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-webdriver-in-java/27837868#27837868

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the `name` value you are passing to your selenium driver and the `name` property you are setting up do not match.

Change this: `WebElement descriptionOne=driver.findElement(By.name("description"));` to this: `WebElement descriptionOne=driver.findElement(By.name("description_long"));`

Answer (score 0):

It is best for you to use id when it is possible. If element does not have an id then you may use the "cssselector". You just write down the jquery as a parameter to,

*driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("jquery"));*

For your problem;

*driver.findElement(By.id("description"));*

*driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#description"));*